# richTextBox proper tab setting

Tags: c#, tabs, richtextbox, margin

I have a list in my `richTextBox` and I want it to look better. I add the attributes one-by-one, of course from variables, but this is the concept:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText("attr1 - ");
richTextBox1.AppendText("some text\r\n");
richTextBox1.AppendText("attr2 - ");
richTextBox1.AppendText("some even longer text\r\n");
//etc...
```

This is how it looks like now:

```
atrr1 - some text
attr2 - some even longer
text
attr3 - some text
```

This is what I need:

```
atrr1 - some text
attr2 - some even longer
        text
attr3 - some text
```

The wrapping should be automatic, I don't want horizontal scroll-bar in my tool. I wish I could share some code but unfortunately I couldn't find any way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use stringbuilder to achieve your goal and write code formatted like a html table:

```
 StringBuilder tableRtf = new StringBuilder();
 tableRtf.Append(@"\trowd \trgraph \cellx1000 Content text of cell \cell\row\pard\par");  
 richTextBox1.Rtf = tableRtf.ToString();
```

so you can use it in a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS_NUMBER; i++)
 {
        //add cell with columns
 }

\trowd --> start table
\trgraph --> start paragraph
\cellx1000 --> cell with width of 1000
```

refer [this](http://techymedia.com/post/2012/08/12/Table-in-Richtextbox-Using-C.aspx) likn for documentation